# Multiple responses on node.js restler call

Tags: javascript, node.js, restler

I've created a library for sending REST requests:

```
var rest = require('restler');
module.exports = {
  beginSession: function()
  {
    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        query: {begin_session: '1'}};
    rest.get('http://countly/i', options).
        on('complete', function(data, response){
            console.log('Status: ' + response.statusCode);
        });
  }
};
```

The problem is that every time I use the library and the call is responded, the 'on complete' is called multiple times: 1st use of method will call 'on complete' just once, 2nd use of method will call 'on complete' twice and so on....

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Jose

Answer (score 14):

I was struggling with this one as well. but didn't find an answer on the internet. I finally figure it out though. It was caused by the 'complete' event being registered *every time* the your rest.get() is called.

My solution is to use .once() instead of .on(). For example:

```
var rest = require('restler');
rest.get('url_to_fetch').once('complete', function(rtn, rsp){
     ....blah blah....
});
// refer here http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_event_listener
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I would expect this to break with concurrent requests.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Bug in restler, quick fix until npm is updated: add git master to `package.json`

The real problem here is that some changes to the event API in node 0.10 results in restler refiring old event listeners as described in https://github.com/danwrong/restler/issues/112.

End of august this was fixed in https://github.com/danwrong/restler/pull/113. While we wait for a proper npm release it works for me by using the current git head.

```
"restler": "git://github.com/danwrong/restler.git#9d455ff14c57ddbe263dbbcd0289d76413bfe07d"
```

DISCLAIMER: I don't know what is broken in this version or why it is not released yet. I did not go trough the issues or diffs since last release to find out.

UPDATE Aug 2014: There was a npm release since then, it seems to include the fix.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you attach a new event for each call. Try to unbind event first.

Comment: Thanks Aleko!. I've implemented your suggestion by removing the Listener on the callback function:        
`var restCall = rest.get(countlyUrl , options).on('complete', callback);   function callback(data, response) {console.log('Status: ' + response.statusCode);restCall.removeListener('complete', callback);};`. But now I have a doubt on how to match each request with each callback. What if I have different callbacks for simultanous requests?

Answer (score 1):

An exception occurring in your callback handler for a JSON request can also cause this behaviour.

See the pull request here for a solution for that:
https://github.com/danwrong/restler/pull/94

Answer (score 1):

Please check out v3.2.2. Upgrade your package.json:

```
npm install restler --save
```

It solved this issue for me.

Comment: @arco444 what exactly do you want me to say? I said what he needs to listen! It's a bug! upgrade your npm packge to v3.2.2 and you will be just fine!

Comment: I'm saying this because my code is pretty much identical of the author of this issue and upgrading the restler version solved the issue for me.

Comment: @arco444 I edited my original answer just for you :*

Comment: Oh god... low quality according to who? you? I have 100% of sure that the person who are having issues will appreciate my answer.

Comment: I don't know what discussion just went on but Igor is correct in that it was a terrible Restler bug. I spent many hours debugging this. Upgrading from 2.0.1 to 3.2.2 fixed the memory leaks and multiple calls I was experiencing.