# unexpected recursion in restler call (node/js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, restler

I want to get a URI, parse it, and then get another URI based on the parsed data.  Using restler, I thought I could do the parsing and the second get call from the .on('complete',...)  function of the first get call.  It doesn't seem to work as I expect.  To investigate, I coded up the following, which is a very simplified version of how my code is structured. It never exits until I hit Ctrl-C.

```
var sys = require('util');
var rest = require('restler');

function UriCall( uri, handler ) {
    rest.get(uri).on('complete', function(result) {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            sys.puts('Error: ' + result.message);
        }
        else {
            if (handler) { handler( result ); }
            else { sys.puts('No handler provided.'); }
        }
    });
} 

var uri = "http://www.google.com";

UriCall(uri, function(result) {
   sys.print("@");
   UriCall(uri, function(result) {
      sys.print(".");
   });
});
```

Output:

```
$node resttest.js

@@.@..@...@....@.....@......@.......@........@ [deleted error messages] .........@..........@...........@............@.............@..............@...............@................@.................@..................@...................@....................@.....................@......................@.......................@........................@.........................@..........................@...........................@............................@.............................@..............................@...............................@................................@.................................@..................................@...................................  ^C
```

From the output above it looks like something is getting stacked up with each call and it just gets deeper and deeper.  I'm a C/C++ guy who is just getting started with js/node/restler. Why doesn't the program simply call UriCall twice and then exit?

(BTW: The errors messages start with *"(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit."* and then included some trace.  The error message doesn't surprise me given what appears to be happening.)

Answer (score 1):

When you attach the event listeners to the `'complete'` event, they don't go away after the event happens (they will run again with the same callback method you put in originally when any `'complete'` is detected). Every successful call to your uri will trigger this event. So you are basically stacking up function calls on the `'complete'` event, and the recursive call in the first callback adds more each time the original event is triggered. Does that make sense?

I suggest using `.once` instead of `.on`, as was suggested here ([Multiple responses on node.js restler call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047761/multiple-responses-on-node-js-restler-call)).  Or unbind the event upon success.

Comment: Thanks. Using rest.get.once did the trick.  Output: @.  So, every call to rest.get.on appends a new event handler?  I assume there is some scope to the event list, that normally the event handler gets unbound, but here because of the nested call it never gets a chance to?

Comment: @jbirkel. Correct. If you want it to map multiple times, but you might call it more than once, you can name it something like `complete.UriCall` and do an `.off('complete.UriCall')` before you call the `on`. Everything before the period is the event name, and everything afterwards is just for differentiating it later on.

Comment: On/off -- that's good to know.  I was thinking of it as "onComplete"  Thanks, Colin.